# How to convert single zip name using perl?

Tags: perl

For example folder contains 10 XML File. Convert the folder to Single Zip file with that folder name

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Compress::Zip qw(zip $ZipError) ; 

my $file = $ENV{"HOME"}."C:/zip";

my $s = zip [ $file, $file2 ] => $ENV{"HOME"}."C:/zip/new_.zip" , zip64 => 1 
    or die "zip failed: $ZipError \n";
```

**Update:** Suggested code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Compress::Zip qw(zip $ZipError) ; 

my $files="C:/zip";

my @file = "<$files/*.xml>";
zip \@file => 'output.zip'
  or die "zip failed: $ZipError\n";
```

**Update:** Suggested code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Compress::Zip qw(zip $ZipError) ; 
my $dir="C:/zip";

my @files = <$dir/*.xml>;

print @files;

zip \@files => 'output.zip'         
    or die "zip failed: $ZipError\n";
```

Comment: Anything you tried on your own? Could you please share your effort with us ?

Comment: Please can you add more content to the question, including any code snippets and what you have tried, Please have a good read here on how to ask a question:

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Compress::Zip qw(zip $ZipError) ; 

my $file = $ENV{"HOME"}."C:/zip";


my $s = zip [ $file, $file2 ] => $ENV{"HOME"}."C:/zip/new_.zip" , zip64 => 1 
        or die "zip failed: $ZipError \n";

Comment: can you please tell where i add the code

Comment: @jawahar: Please don't dump code into comments where it is really hard to read. Instead, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40631276/edit) to add the code.

Comment: simply convert folder to zip..please help

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that prepending `$ENV{HOME}` to all of your filenames is a good idea - when the filenames you're using are all absolute paths that start with `C:/`. What error message do you see?

Comment: can you please edit my code it not work

Comment: I know it doesn't work. But if I was to just give you the complete solution, that wouldn't be very useful for you, would it? I'm trying to find out what you misunderstand, so that I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: ya thanks..For example folder contains 10 XML File. Convert the folder to Single Zip file with that folder name...I dont have idea to convert zip

Comment: If you have no idea where to start, then where did the code you've added to your question come from?

Comment: @jawahar: The code you have just edited into your question looks good. I would just suggest renaming `$files` to `$dir` and `@file` to `@files`. I think that my names better identify what is in those variables. But congratulations on working it out.

Comment: But error comes zip failed: input file '<C:/zip/*.xml>' does not exist

Comment: @jawahar: You don't need those quotes. `@file = <$files/*.xml>;`

Comment: Ya it work fine..But one small doubt..I dont need inside another folder..Zip inside file that enough. It create zip start with C:/

Comment: I feel confident that you're up to solving that last little problem.

Comment: Ya i am trying if not means please tell

Comment: my @files = <$dir/*.xml>; ..can i match regex with separate xml only

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. There's no regex in any of this code. Why not post a new question with your current code and explain what problems you're having.

Comment: I dont want zip with compleate folder ...i need only zip the xml file..but it zipped entire foder starting with C:/zip/xml

Comment: Why not post a new question with your current code and explain what problems you're having

Comment: my @files = <$dir/*.xml>;  zip \@files => 'output.zip' ..I need *.xml only ..not $dir to zip..

Comment: Sounds like you want to change directory before running `zip()`.

Comment: Or perhaps before setting `@files`.

Comment: I want to zip the xml file only ,,not with entire folder to zip..but it zip the entire folder..how i zip xml only

Comment: Why not post a new question with your current code and explain what problems you're having

Comment: sorry one day one question only ask..please help this my last scenario to compleate my project...

Comment: `chdir $dir; my @files = <*.xml>;` Or something like that, I suspect.

Comment: Thank you so much..It working fine

Comment: @jawahar: If my help was useful, you might consider accepting my answer.

Comment: yes...You are hacker

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for the module that you are using](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Compress::Zip) seems to have some examples which are very close to what you are trying to do.

```
my @files = <*.txt>;
zip \@files => 'output.zip'
    or die "zip failed: $ZipError\n";
```

Or

```
zip [ <*.txt> ] => 'output.zip'
    or die "zip failed: $ZipError\n";
```

You just need to edit that to include the directory name in a couple of places.

Comment: i want to zip specific path.

Comment: Simply i want to specific the path to zip ex: my @files = "C:/zip<*.xml>";

Comment: I know. And that is why I wrote "you just need to edit that to include the directory name in a couple of places".

Comment: I can, yes. But I'm not going to. Honestly, this really isn't hard. You're going to have to make a little bit of effort here. Your profile says that you're a programmer. A programmer would know how to research the syntax required to make these changes. A programmer would have been able to read the module documentation and find the examples I have given you. If you're a programmer, you can do this. If you're not a programmer then you should pay someone to write this for you. We are not here to write your code for you. We are here to help fellow programmers solve problems in their code.

Comment: @jawahar: Please don't suggest edits to my answer - particularly not ones that don't solve the problem. If you have new code for us to look at, then please edit your question to include it.